# Apache HTTPS redirect to Tomcat web folder

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, tomcat, mod-ssl

I have configured my server to use httpd as proxy and Tomcat for deploying and running application. I use Apache httpd as proxy to redirect all request to port 80 and to the directory of tomcat where my web application files are located: `/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/website`.

The proxy lines that redirects to `http://localhost:8080/website` works for me, but when I tried to use HTTPS by adding additional lines like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

then it just redirects to directory of Apache that is located in `/var/www/html` with default Apache httpd page.

This are my configurations in my conf.file:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/website/
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://website.com:8080/website/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://website.com:8080/website/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.3 +TLSv1.2
    SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves X25519:secp521r1:secp384r1:prime256v1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domein.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/domein-demo.key
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

The results that I get is

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

I have already tried giving permissions to Apache to directory of Tomcat with `sudo chown apache:apache /usr/share/webapps/website`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question: when you access your site through HTTP (port 80) you want to: 1. redirect the browser to the HTTPS port, 2. forward the request to Tomcat **or** 3. retrieve the data in the `/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/website` directory? Your configuration performs the first operation.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You're redirecting all requests that's not HTTPS to its HTTPS counterpart, and HTTPS requests are handled by `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` configurations instead of `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Try copying or moving these configurations:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://website.com:8080/website/
ProxyPassReverse / http://website.com:8080/website/
```

from `<VirtualHost *:80>` configuration block to `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`.

Comment: Hi mforsetti, that solved my problem, than you

Comment: just one more question with current configuration httpd redirects to my website only when i surf with WWW www.website.com so when i try to surf to http://website.com without www then i get page 404  i am guessing it can not find the the application files.

Comment: So i have reconfigure the redirect engine part
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.website.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.website.com/%1 [R=301,L]

but this is not helping

Comment: You are using lots of conditions. Keep it simple: if you want to redirect all HTTP request to HTTPS use `RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` or `RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` without any conditions.

Comment: hi Piotr, i tried by disabling all conditions and using only this rules RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]  But no results i get 404 page not found but when i use www i get the whole page.

Comment: is it posibble that my certificate is not properly generated? maby i should regenerate certificate and add -alias www.website.com  
Second question, do i need to add or change somethink in server.xml file of tomcat /usr/share/tomcat/server.xml? the only code that i have added inside server.xml is
              ` <Host name="website.com"  appBase="website"
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" />`